# Marker doesn't get added on map

Tags: flutter, dart

As seen in picture pressing green button should add a marker to map which in my case is not working

Here is link to: https://github.com/fireship-io/167-flutter-geolocation-firestore

i have tried on real device aswell as different emulators

Data is getting inserted in firebase database but not showing on map

there are no errors in app aswell

[image]

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Maps',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Map Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  StreamSubscription _locationSubscription;
  Location _locationTracker = Location();
  Marker marker;
  Circle circle;
  GoogleMapController _controller;

  static final CameraPosition initialLocation = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  Future<Uint8List> getMarker() async {
    ByteData byteData = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).load("assets/car_icon.png");
    return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  void updateMarkerAndCircle(LocationData newLocalData, Uint8List imageData) {
    LatLng latlng = LatLng(newLocalData.latitude, newLocalData.longitude);
    this.setState(() {
      marker = Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId("home"),
          position: latlng,
          rotation: newLocalData.heading,
          draggable: false,
          zIndex: 2,
          flat: true,
          anchor: Offset(0.5, 0.5),
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(imageData));
      circle = Circle(
          circleId: CircleId("car"),
          radius: newLocalData.accuracy,
          zIndex: 1,
          strokeColor: Colors.blue,
          center: latlng,
          fillColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(70));
    });
  }

  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {

      Uint8List imageData = await getMarker();
      var location = await _locationTracker.getLocation();

      updateMarkerAndCircle(location, imageData);

      if (_locationSubscription != null) {
        _locationSubscription.cancel();
      }


      _locationSubscription = _locationTracker.onLocationChanged().listen((newLocalData) {
        if (_controller != null) {
          _controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(
              bearing: 192.8334901395799,
              target: LatLng(newLocalData.latitude, newLocalData.longitude),
              tilt: 0,
              zoom: 18.00)));
          updateMarkerAndCircle(newLocalData, imageData);
        }
      });

    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        debugPrint("Permission Denied");
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (_locationSubscription != null) {
      _locationSubscription.cancel();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.terrain,
        initialCameraPosition: initialLocation,
        markers: Set.of((marker != null) ? [marker] : []),
        circles: Set.of((circle != null) ? [circle] : []),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller = controller;
        },

      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.location_searching),
          onPressed: () {
            getCurrentLocation();
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am new to flutter but i would suggest to embed google maps within Stack widget

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Stack(children:[GoogleMap(....)])
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you initialise your image (car_icon.png ) in pubspec.yaml

```
 assets:


 - assets/car_icon.png
```

Add dependencies in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.5
location:
```

Now try this code its working perfectly

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Maps',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Map Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  StreamSubscription _locationSubscription;
  Location _locationTracker = Location();
  Marker marker;
  Circle circle;
  GoogleMapController _controller;

  static final CameraPosition initialLocation = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  Future<Uint8List> getMarker() async {
    ByteData byteData = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).load("assets/bong.png");
    return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  void updateMarkerAndCircle(LocationData newLocalData, Uint8List imageData) {
    LatLng latlng = LatLng(newLocalData.latitude, newLocalData.longitude);
    this.setState(() {
      marker = Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId("home"),
          position: latlng,
          rotation: newLocalData.heading,
          draggable: false,
          zIndex: 2,
          flat: true,
          anchor: Offset(0.5, 0.5),
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(imageData));
         // icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset("assets/bong.png"));
      circle = Circle(
          circleId: CircleId("car"),
          radius: newLocalData.accuracy,
          zIndex: 1,
          strokeColor: Colors.blue,
          center: latlng,
          fillColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(70));
    });
  }

  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {

      Uint8List imageData = await getMarker();
      var location = await _locationTracker.getLocation();

      updateMarkerAndCircle(location, imageData);

      if (_locationSubscription != null) {
        _locationSubscription.cancel();
      }


      _locationSubscription = _locationTracker.onLocationChanged.listen((newLocalData) {
        if (_controller != null) {
          _controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(
              bearing: 192.8334901395799,
              target: LatLng(newLocalData.latitude, newLocalData.longitude),
              tilt: 0,
              zoom: 18.00)));
          updateMarkerAndCircle(newLocalData, imageData);
        }
      });

    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        debugPrint("Permission Denied");
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (_locationSubscription != null) {
      _locationSubscription.cancel();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.terrain,
        initialCameraPosition: initialLocation,
        markers: Set.of((marker != null) ? [marker] : []),
        circles: Set.of((circle != null) ? [circle] : []),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller = controller;
        },

      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.location_searching),
          onPressed: () {
            getCurrentLocation();
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

initialise google map api in manifiest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="google map api"/>
```